What is the strict type for the below code in angular
const componentMapper = {
  input: InputComponent,
  button: ButtonComponent,
  select: SelectComponent,
  date: DateComponent,
  radiobutton: RadiobuttonComponent,
  checkbox: CheckboxComponent,
  switch: SwitchComponent,
  textarea: TextAreaComponent
};
const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentMapper[this.field.type]);

What is strict type for const compFactory

What do you think it is, based on what (re)searching?

are you sure you need component factory? since Ivy = angular 9 it is useless. respective APIs that were using factory in the past should accept component class itself. It should simplify your logic

The type of compFactory is
ComponentFactory<
  typeOf InputComponent
  | typeOf ButtonComponent
  | ...
  | typeOf SwitchComponent
  | typeOf TextAreaComponent
>


Since there can be multiple component, best to go for any type. This is more readable.
const componentMapper: { [key: string]: any } = {
  child: Child,
};

Stackblitz Demo
